# Bug in dotchart pch?

Tags: r

I think there may be a bug in the way the pch parameter is read within the dotchart function, but would appreciate peer confirmation before reporting it.

In the following, I would like both colour and symbol to vary with the group.  Colour works fine, as expected, but not symbol.

```
foo <- data.frame(Specimen=paste("Specimen", 1:18),
              Group=c(rep("Benign", 4),
                      rep("In-situ", 6), 
                      rep("Invasive", 8)),
              Outcome=rweibull(18, 5) + (1:18 / 18))

with(foo, dotchart(Outcome, 
     groups = Group,
     color = c("green", "orange", "red")[Group],
     pch=c(16, 15, 17)[Group], 
     xlab="Outcome measure /bar", 
     labels = Specimen))
```

There is an easy but rather bizarre workaround by reversing the "Group" column encoding pch :

```
with(foo, dotchart(Outcome, 
     groups = Group,
     color = c("green", "orange", "red")[Group],
     pch=c(16, 15, 17)[rev(Group)], 
     xlab="Outcome measure /bar", 
     labels = Specimen))
```

However, I cannot see a single legitimate reason why the vector for pch should have to be reversed, particularly since colour seems to work entirely as expected.  Thoughts?

Incidentally, the reason I generally try to vary the symbol as well as the colour for different groups in a chart is for the benefit of colour blind readers.  Granted, it is not so important in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree this may be a bug (which I am genuinely cautious about in base R functions like this).

Specficially, `dotchart` reorders the `color`  and `lcolor` (line color) arguments here:

```
o <- sort.list(as.numeric(groups), decreasing = TRUE)
x <- x[o]
groups <- groups[o]
color <- rep_len(color, length(groups))[o]
lcolor <- rep_len(lcolor, length(groups))[o]
```

...and those are used in the subsequent `abline` and `points` calls, but `pch` is passed on unchanged. The fix would likely be to simply add the line,

```
pch <- rep_len(pch, length(groups))[o]
```

If I wanted to put my pedantic hat on (which is a good idea before submitting a bug report), I would note that the documentation for `?dotchart` specifies:

> color  the color(s) to be used for points and labels.

for the `color` argument, but only:

> pch    the plotting character or symbol to be used.

for the `pch` argument. Some may argue that this "clearly" implies that only `color` is intended to take multiple values, and so in that sense this isn't a "bug".

Comment: Many thanks.  I just tested your solution (created a function "dottychart" with this extra line), and it works fine.  I think I might try to report this, unless you would like to?  I am relatively speaking a beginner and not used to digging around in the guts of base functions!  I cannot see what harm there would be in adding this one line to the code.  I smacks of an oversight rather than a deliberate omission.

Answer (score 0):

This definitely looks like a bug. I have a dataset where samples have a fairly complex 4*4 color+pch coding corresponding to things that are also in the sample names, on top of groups, and the `pch` values just don't seem to be reordered at all during group reordering. I'll try to submit a bug report in the next weeks. I have R 3.6.1

Comment: There was already a 2016 bug report for this https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=16953